# Editing headers in pandas ( python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data as shown below,

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [6,7,8,9,0]
z = [11,12,12,56,6]
```

Now, I want to export this data to an excel file. For that I have used the following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3,4,5],
                     " ":np.nan,
                     "y":[6,7,8,9,0],
                     " ":np.nan,
                     "z":[11,12,12,56,6]})
data.to_excel('test_file.xlsx', index= False)
```

Here I used the `np.nan` to create an empty column.

The new excel file is as shown

[image]

but, I want to show the data as shown in this picture
[image]

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem your dictionary of lists contain duplicate column name `' '` and it is per design not allowed. So is possible create `DataFrame` by [column_stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) and define columns names:

```
empty =  [np.nan] * len(x)
data = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([x,empty,z,empty,y]), columns= ['x','','y','','z'])
```

Or  a little hack - create all unique columns first in `dict` and then `rename`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"x":x,
                     "empty1":np.nan,
                     "y":y,
                     "empty2":np.nan,
                     "z":z}, columns=['x','empty1','y','empty2','z'])
data = data.rename(columns={'empty1':'', 'empty2':''})         

print (data)
     x         y        z
0  1.0 NaN  11.0 NaN  6.0
1  2.0 NaN  12.0 NaN  7.0
2  3.0 NaN  12.0 NaN  8.0
3  4.0 NaN  56.0 NaN  9.0
4  5.0 NaN   6.0 NaN  0.0


data.to_excel('test_file.xlsx', index= False)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way also ( no cost hack :) )

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3,4,5],
                     "": np.nan,
                     "y": [6,7,8,9,0],
                     None: np.nan,
                     "z": [11,12,12,56,6]})
```